# Traffic utilization on Cisco and Juniper devices

Tags: cisco, juniper

I'd like to check current traffic utilization (how much Mb/s is used per interface) on port on cisco switch and Juniper SRX device - any ideas where I can look up for this informations?

Thank you for all answers.
mfx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Cisco devices, you can type

```
show interface x/y
```

You'll get a response like this

```
Router>show interface tengigabit 0/0/0
TenGigabitEthernet0/0/0 is up, line protocol is up 
  Hardware is SPA-1X10GE-L-V2, address is 0000.0000.0000 (bia 0000.0000.0000)
  Description: Sample Circuit
  Internet address is 1.2.3.4/31
  MTU 9178 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 9/255, rxload 11/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not supported 
  Full Duplex, 10000Mbps, link type is force-up, media type is 10GBase-LR
  output flow-control is on, input flow-control is on
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:29, output 00:00:04, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/375/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 456145000 bits/sec, 85866 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 356961000 bits/sec, 79293 packets/sec
     405059988918 packets input, 267595313186384 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 2 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles 
     832 input errors, 677 CRC, 155 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 3635928 multicast, 0 pause input
     381317901828 packets output, 215556748770785 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
Router>
```

For simple utilization, txload and rxload will give you the answer (6th line down).  The values
are expressed as fractional utilization out of 255.  So 0/255 is 0 load, 128/255 is 50% load and 255/255 is 100% load.  In this case, 9/255 is a little over 3%. For actual byte counts, look at the 5 minute input and output rates.  Although it should be obvious, it bears repeating that these numbers are 5 minute averages.

Answer (score 2):

For Juniper devices you can use the `monitor interface` command, it shows an overview of all interface counters which is automatically updated:

```
user@host> monitor interface fe-0/0/0

host1                           Seconds: 5                   Time: 04:38:40
                                                          Delay: 3/0/10
Interface: fe-0/0/0, Enabled, Link is Up
Encapsulation: Ethernet, Speed: 1000mbps
Traffic statistics:                                           Current delta
  Input bytes:                 885405423 (3248 bps)                  [2631]
  Output bytes:                137411893 (3344 bps)                 [10243]
  Input packets:                 7155064 (2 pps)                       [28]
  Output packets:                 636071 (1 pps)                       [23]
Error statistics:
  Input errors:                        0                                [0]
  Input drops:                         0                                [0]
  Input framing errors:                0                                [0]
  Policed discards:                    0                                [0]
  L3 incompletes:                      0                                [0]
  L2 channel errors:                   0                                [0]
  L2 mismatch timeouts:                0                                [0]
  Carrier transitions:                 1                                [0]
  Output errors:                       0                                [0]
  Output drops:                        0                                [0]
  Aged packets:                        0                                [0]
Active alarms : None
Active defects: None
Input MAC/Filter statistics:
  Unicast packets                  73083                               [16]
  Broadcast packets              3629058                                [5]
  Multicast packets              3511364                                [3]
  Oversized frames                     0                                [0]
  Packet reject count                  0                                [0]
  DA rejects                           0                                [0]
  SA rejects                           0                                [0]
Output MAC/Filter Statistics:
  Unicast packets                 629555                               [28]
  Broadcast packets                 6494  Multicast packet              [0]
```

More details can be found in the [JunOS documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/operational/security-real-time-interface-information-displaying.html).